# Installing Tensorflow in Rstudio?

Tags: python, anaconda, rstudio, tensor

I've been trying to follow the tutorial here:
https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2017-12-07-text-classification-with-keras/
and here:
https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/installation/

When it comes to installing and using tensorflow. However I have been getting errors. I have a version of anaconda 3 on my Mac, along with python.

```
install.packages("keras")
install.packages("tensorflow")
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()
library(tensorflow)
tf$constant("Hello Tensorflow")
```

I get the following error message:

```
Detected Python configuration:

python:         /usr/bin/python
libpython:      /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib
pythonhome:     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
version:        2.7.16 (default, Oct 16 2019, 00:34:56)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)]
numpy:          /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy
numpy_version:  1.8.0
tensorflow:     [NOT FOUND]
```

I assume there is a simple workaround, but I haven't been able to get anything to work so far? Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

It seems tensorflow isn't installed - that explains the message [NOT FOUND].
Could you open your Anaconda environments and check that? If you choose the option installed in the dropdown and search for it you should know the answer. In that case you can install it via Anaconda.

Comment: So I installed tensorflow in an environment in Anaconda and it works in the R Studio within Anaconda. Is there a way to get it to work in my original instance of R Studio that I had before I installed Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install the package via CRAN in your previous version of R Studio as the following Screenshot shows:
[image]